# How to make unit test for method with NetworkStream param?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, network-programming, networkstream

I'm beginner in testing.I need to create unit test for method with NetworkStream like that:

```
void Do(NetworkStream str)
{...}
```

Comment: To give a good answer to this question I would need some context. Perhaps you shouldn't test the method Do(), but something bigger or different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the input parameter to be of type Stream. You can then call the method with a prepared MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly NetworkStream is not mockable.
You will have to create a custom "MockNetworkStream" to test everything you will encounter from stream.

For more information, check this: [How to moq a NetworkStream in a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176975/how-to-moq-a-networkstream-in-a-unit-test)