# Mocking a Stream to Read byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, nunit, moq

My SUT requires a `Stream` as a parameter, does some work and then returns a `byte[]`:

```
public byte[] ProcessRequest(INetworkStream networkStream)
```

`INetworkStream` wraps `Stream`.

I want to mock the `Stream` parameter to have control over what bytes it reads so I can test the method with these bytes.

```
stream.Read(buffer, offset, size);
```

`Stream.Read(...)` returns an `int` and populates the `buffer` parameter.

Using `Moq` how do I fake the result of the call to `INetworkStream.Read(...)` (So I control both the length of the `byte[]` as the return value and also the `buffer` parameter)?

The [Stream wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176975/how-to-moq-a-networkstream-in-a-unit-test/2177087#2177087):

```
public class FakeNetworkStream : INetworkStream
{
    private NetworkStream stream;

    public FakeNetworkStream(NetworkStream ns)
    {
        if (ns == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ns");
        this.stream = ns;
    }

    public bool DataAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stream.DataAvailable;
        }
    }

    public int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        return this.stream.Read(buffer, offset, size);
    }

    public void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size)
    {
        this.stream.Write(buffer, offset, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: `INetworkStream` wraps `Stream` --> That seems strange, because `INetworkStream` seems to be an interface while `Stream` is a class. An interface can't derive from a class. So what's really going on here?

Comment: I said wraps, not derives. It wraps it...

Comment: Yeah, but that's impossible. An interface is just a contract definition. It can't wrap anything because there is no implementation.

Comment: The interface defines the contract while the implementation implements the contract and wraps `Stream`.

Comment: Since your SUT requires an `INetworkStream` you don't need to care about the implementation. That's why you use interfaces in the first place :-)

Comment: What's your point? I cannot mock a `Stream` so I need something to replace it with. So I have created `INetworkStream` so I can take control over `Stream`.

Comment: My point is: Simply mock `INetworkStream`. No need to care about `Stream` (which you don't use anyway. You use `NetworkStream`). Oh, and read my answer...

Comment: That is what I am doing. :) I am mocking `INetworkStream`.

Comment: Eh... So what's your question? You now got me really confused.

Comment: You've answered my question in your answer. :) It is 'Using Moq how do I fake the result of the call to INetworkStream.Read(...) (So I control both the length of the byte[] as the return value and also the buffer parameter)?'

Comment: OK, glad I could help. Still a bit confused though ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you got a little bit confused by the answer that you linked to. You now have an interface `INetworkStream`. Simply mock it.
No need to use `NetworkStream` or `Stream` in your tests (refer to the last bit of code in the original *question*, it contains the code you want to use. Disregard the answer that has been posted on the question.)

You would setup your mock something like that:

```
var stream = new Mock<INetworkStream>();
stream.Setup(x => x.Read(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
      .Callback((byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) =>
                {
                    Array.Copy(tempBuffer, offset, buffer, 0, size) 
                }
               )
      .Returns((byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) => size);
```

Please note that I am not a Moq user, so my syntax here might be a bit off, but it should convey the idea on how to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the Array Copy method

```
stream.Setup(x => x.Read(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
              .Callback((byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) =>
              {
                  Array.Copy(tempBuffer, offset, buffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
              })
              .Returns((byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) => size);
```